How would I build my tauri app using tauri_cli::run command?
As the title say, I'm trying to build my tauri app using a cargo build command.
My goal was to make a mono binary using all my crates, one of them being a tauri app.
They previously all had their own binary and I made them into libs.
What I've tried is to build the app inside the build.rs of my tauri crate, by calling tauri_cli::run(["build"], None).
This however builds indefinitely because it is stuck at the build-script-build part.
Executing cargo tauri build inside the crate of my tauri app works fine.
This is my first time at trying to make a ""release"" build and honestly, I'm not sure what I'm doing.

i would say you restructure your project in a way that Cargo can handle a workspace efficiently like this : my_project/
├── Cargo.toml
├── tauri_app/
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── main.rs
├── other_crate/
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── lib.rs
└── src/
└── main.rs
then configure the workspace by editing the cargo.toml : [workspace]
members = ["tauri_app", "other_crate"]
. now build the script for tauri but be mindful that, Instead of calling tauri_cli::run(["build"], None) in the build.rs, which can lead to infinite recursion,configure your build

@AdesojiAlu I should have mentioned that he workspace was already set up.
I was afraid you'd say this can lead infinite recursion (and it's the problem I'm having).

I figured I just had to exec the beforeBuildCommand I had in my tauri.conf.json inside the build.rs, however this not seem to be enough as I am now getting event.listen not allowed. Plugin did not define its manifest in the webconsole.

i would say that you should Handle Tauri Build Process, now Instead of calling tauri_cli::run(["build"], None) in build.rs, you should handle the Tauri build process using a different approach to avoid infinite recursion. You can use a script or a makefile to orchestrate the build step
Create a script (e.g., build.sh) to handle the build process like this
#!/bin/bash

# Build the Tauri app
cd tauri_app
cargo tauri build
cd ..

# Build the workspace
cargo build --release



now make sure you make  the script executable if you are in a linux environment by doing
chmod +x build.sh


Then, run the script to build your project like this in the same path or directory
./build.sh


Furthermore, try to use makefile to manage the build process by doing
.PHONY: all tauri-build workspace-build

all: tauri-build workspace-build

tauri-build:
    cd tauri_app && cargo tauri build

workspace-build:
    cargo build --release


then you run the make command
make


thanks for the answer ! But my goal was to handle the build process of my entire app (including the tauri part) in a simple cargo build call. I guess I should try to mimic what cargo tauri build does in order to achieve that.
